# 404 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php

I have data about 2000 students in report format and i want to export to excel complete data. for this i had write down the code in which i had create a form in which hidden field exists that contain complete data on export button with the help of javascript. AFter post the form

```
function export_data()   {      
    $length = strlen($_REQUEST['export_data']);         
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');  
    $File_Name = 'Exam_Form_Report_'.date('Y-m-d').'.xls';
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$File_Name);  
    // Fix for crappy IE bug in download.  
    header("Pragma: ");
    header("Cache-Control: ");      header('Content-Length: '.$length);
    echo $_REQUEST['export_data'];
    exit;   
}
```

above function is called. But when i click on export button than i have to face error :-

```
Request Entity Too Large The requested resource /rau/counselling/rauexam/rau/sis_reports/export_data does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

or In case of offline it's working fine. (I also increase post_max_limit but problem is not resolved.) Please any one can  provide proper solution.

Comment: Can you show the code that is providing $_REQUEST['export_data'] to this method? are you submitting that data using GET or POST? If you aren't using POST, then changing your 'post_max_limit' wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: Looks to me like you're submitting a large number of check box values. Try limiting the number of inputs on a page, or think of a way to serialise the data before submitting(so instead of submitting 2,000 checkboxes and a status simply submit one input with a value of IDs for your checkboxes, comma separated.)

Comment: Yes, I am using form method as post. 

echo $this->form->create('sis_reports', array('Id'=>'sis_reports','action'=>'export_data', 'name'=>'sis_reports', 'update'=>'', 'legend'=>false));